# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/view/ActionMode$Callback.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, executable-jar

i import one project in my Android studio so my build.gradle file as follows.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pkg.name"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
   }
 }

dependencies {
compile files('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/itextpdf-5.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.48.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

when i run my project it gives me error like below:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/view/ActionMode$Callback.class
```

Any idea how can i solve this problem? All your suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: Why you added two times `android-support-v7-appcompat`?. remove any one

Comment: M D : yes you are right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're including the appcompat library twice:

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

Also please note that there are some other adjustments you need to make for multidex support: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Daniele Ricci : after your solution, now i  gave error like below link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512910/org-gradle-process-internal-execexception-process-command-c-program-files-ja](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512910/org-gradle-process-internal-execexception-process-command-c-program-files-ja) Any idea about that

Comment: I've never tried multidex, can you post your new configuration and problem in a separate question please?

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya Is that question from your fake account?